# Are there any differences between `/etc` and `/private/etc`?

Tags: macos, mac

Are there any differences between `/etc` and `/private/etc` on Mac OS X?

Comment: FYI, in Mac OS, `/etc` links to `/private/etc`.

Comment: tnx, what's about /usr ? shouldn't it link to /Users/myUser ?

Comment: @gilsilas: I suggest you have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: FileSystem Hierarchy Standard is just for Linux and not for Unix - for OSX see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System for the disk structure and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/BPFileSystem.html for the directories

Comment: @gilsias Regarding @Felix's answer: No! /usr is not where user home folders are located in (most) Linux distros!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On i386/darwin10.0/10.7.0:

```
%  ls -aFGl / | grep private
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel        11 Apr 28  2010 etc@ -> private/etc
drwxr-xr-x@   6 root  wheel       204 Apr 28  2010 private/
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel        11 Apr 28  2010 tmp@ -> private/tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel        11 Apr 28  2010 var@ -> private/var

%  ls -aFGl /private
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root  wheel   204 Apr 28  2010 ./
drwxrwxr-t  32 root  admin  1156 Jan 19 10:04 ../
drwxr-xr-x  95 root  wheel  3230 Apr  7 07:06 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    68 Jan 27  2010 tftpboot/
drwxrwxrwt   9 root  wheel   306 Apr 15 09:03 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  26 root  wheel   884 Apr 28  2010 var/
```

So `/etc` is a [*symlink*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink). To `/private/etc`, which is a directory. They both have the same contents. The same is true for `/tmp` and `/var`.

Comment: The same with `/var` and `/tmp`.

Comment: Regarding your command, I'm curious, what's your alias/function `ls` definition?